# Error 404, Unable to find service index for the source

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore, jfrog-cli

I am trying to run a nuget restore to download the packages from  JFrog artifactory. While doing so , I am getting 404 error. What I have noticed is that if I manually download the package , it stores it in the cache. Once it is available in the cache, the nuget restore command is able to download the packages. If the manual step isn't performed it fails to locate the packages and throws a 404 error. Has anybody come across this

[image: Service index not found for the source]

Answer (score 0):

From past experience with Nuget (And specifically some of the packages in the logs),
If you have Xray with a block download policy you will get 404 from Nuget Restore.
Additionally, If Xray was configured and is now not working it might block downloads in the same way.

I would look in Artifactory logs (artifactory-service.log) to see what is blocking the download of the packages and if it's indeed Xray you can solve it with Xray configuration.

Comment: I am able to download the packages from curl and UI - So it is nuget specific issue